# How to not exclude leading or trailing whitespace with this regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am using this regex in javascript:

```
search.split(/\s+/g);
```

However, I find that it gives me

```
input          output
`car`          ["car"]
`car `         ["car",""]
` car`         ["","car"]
` car `        ["","car",""]
` car is `     ["","car","is",""]
```

How can I change the regex so that I do not get leading or trailing `""`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is not to change the regex but to stop using `.split`:

```
var parts = search.match(/\S+/g) || [];
```